How to Show Hide tag Image When one of Owl Carousel item active?
I have an issue to show and hide image, it's not working. How to if the owl-carousel active item that has id="img-dark" will show img id="dark" div and hide img id="light"?
I have tried to try this
HTML
<div class="brand-name font-custom">
   <img src="img/logo.svg" class="logoheader" id="logo-light">
   <img src="img/logodark.svg" class="logoheader" id="logo-dark" style="display: none;">
</div>

JQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
        var visible = owl.find('.owl-item.active').find('#img-dark').is(':visible');
        if (visible) {
            $("#logo-dark").show();
            $("#logo-light").hide();
        } else {
            $("#logo-dark").hide();
            $("#logo-light").show();
        }
    });
});

Please help me solve this problem

Can you add a minimal reproducible code? so that its easier to help.
